# What is the name of this moving color pixels effect, for animating a painting?

Tags: color, animation, pixels, colorspace

https://superrare.co/artwork-v2/spring-22267

The artwork in the link seems to be based on a painting of a woman, but effects have been added that assign a pixel to each block of the painting that shift in color and contrast across a certain number of frames as part of a gif animation, although the original painting itself doesn't move underneath.

- is there a name for this effect?
- and could someone breifly outline the steps of how it can be achieved
  in software?
- any popular examples where this effect is used or first introduced?

Answer (score 2):

This effect is called [Color Cycling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_cycling) (or Palette Shifting). Mark Ferrari has a great [GDC talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMcJ1Jvtef0) where he demonstrates and explains the entire technique. You can view a bunch of his artwork based on this technique [here](http://www.effectgames.com/demos/canvascycle/).

The main idea is that each pixel is painted not with a single color, but as values of a look-up table to a palette of colors. The entire image then cycles through the palettes frame by frame. Assigning colors to each palette to create the illusion of movement requires a fair bit of artistry. Mark Ferrari does this in a software called Pro Motion, but this can be coded in a shader pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it’s based on a [halftone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halftone) technique, with the grid warped using a few sine waves. Not sure about how the colors are being assigned, but there’s some kind of [quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization) going on.

Comment: which software contains halftone and quantization pre-set effects for the video-ization of a still image?

Comment: You might be able to get close with After Effects and some combination of plugins, but the artist most likely wrote their own custom software for it in an environment like [Processing](https://processing.org) or [Shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com).

Comment: the following video achieves the same effect, but instead of a still image, it does it for a motion video, plus exhibits depth for each pixel. Adobe premiere, however, does not have a video "quantization" effect. If it's called quantization for a still image, what is that same effect called for video? https://foundation.app/pai/fable-of-fortune-pai-17031

Comment: Same thing. Premiere is not meant for doung effects use after effects.